# How to automate the tenant creation in openstack using python

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-python-api

I want to first source the admin rc file and then need to automate the tenant create using python(openstack) amd new to this..please help me out

Comment: How about using something like Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

**Using REST APIs**:

**Step-1**: Generate the token for authentication using the admin rc file details.

Use the keystone API for generating the auth token - https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=create-project-detail#authentication-and-token-management

**Step-2**: Access the "create project" (keystone v3) API to create the project (before we call it as tenant which uses keystone v2 version).

https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=create-project-detail#create-project